# Modifying and Show Ques. Randomly in the Quiz with navigation

Tags: javascript, random, navigation

I'm working on this quiz.
This is the Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rpscadda/vwpctcjg/

```js
 var quiztitle = "Social Security Quiz";


 var quiz = [
        {
            "question" : "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
            "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg/220px-Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                    "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                    "Albert Einstein",
                                    "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Albert Einstein",
            "explanation" : "Albert Einstein drafted the special theory of relativity in 1905.",
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q2: Who is on the two dollar bill?",
            "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/US_%242_obverse-high.jpg/320px-US_%242_obverse-high.jpg",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Thomas Jefferson",
                                    "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
                                    "Benjamin Franklin",
                                    "Abraham Lincoln"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Thomas Jefferson",
            "explanation" : "The two dollar bill is seldom seen in circulation. As a result, some businesses are confused when presented with the note.",
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q3: What event began on April 12, 1861?",
            "image" : "",
            "choices" : [
                                    "First manned flight",
                                    "California became a state",
                                    "American Civil War began",
                                    "Declaration of Independence"
                                ],
            "correct" : "American Civil War began",
            "explanation" : "South Carolina came under attack when Confederate soldiers attacked Fort Sumter. The war lasted until April 9th 1865.",
        },
     

    ];


 var currentquestion = 0,
     score = 0,
     submt = true,
     picked;

 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


     function htmlEncode(value) {
         return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
     }


     function addChoices(choices) {
         if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
             $('#choice-block').empty();
             for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                 $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
             }
         }
     }

     function nextQuestion() {
         submt = true;
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
         $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
         if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
             if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
                 $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
             } else {
                 $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
             }
         } else {
             $('#question-image').remove();
         }
         addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
         setupButtons();


     }


     function processQuestion(choice) {
         if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#50D943'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
             score++;
         } else {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#D92623'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
         }
         currentquestion++;
         $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION &raquo;').on('click', function () {
             if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                 endQuiz();
             } else {
                 $(this).text('Check Answer').css({
                     'color': '#222'
                 }).off('click');
                 nextQuestion();
             }
         })
     }


     function setupButtons() {
         $('.choice').on('mouseover', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#e1e1e1'
             });
         });
         $('.choice').on('mouseout', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#fff'
             });
         })
         $('.choice').on('click', function () {
             picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
             $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
             $(this).css({
                 'border-color': '#222',
                 'font-weight': 700,
                 'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
             });
             if (submt) {
                 submt = false;
                 $('#submitbutton').css({
                     'color': '#000'
                 }).on('click', function () {
                     $('.choice').off('click');
                     $(this).off('click');
                     processQuestion(picked);
                 });
             }
         })
     }


     function endQuiz() {
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').empty();
         $('#choice-block').empty();
         $('#submitbutton').remove();
         $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
         $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
             'text-align': 'center',
             'font-size': '4em'
         }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');
     }


     function init() {
         //add title
         if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
             $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
         } else {
             $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
         }

         //add pager and questions
         if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
             //add pager
             $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
             //add first question
             $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
             //add image if present
             if (quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != "") {
                 $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
             }
             $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

             //questions holder
             $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

             //add choices
             addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

             //add submit button
             $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('Check Answer').css({
                 'font-weight': 700,
                 'color': '#222',
                 'padding': '30px 0'
             }).appendTo('#frame');

             setupButtons();
         }
     }

     init();
 });
```

```css
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
  /*css reset */
  html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, code, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, b, u, i {
      border:0;
      font-size:100%;
      font:inherit;
      vertical-align:baseline;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
      display:block;
  }
  body {
      line-height:1;
      font:normal 0.9em/1em"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  ol, ul {
      list-style:none;
  }
  strong {
      font-weight:700;
  }
  #frame {
      max-width:620px;
      width:auto;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      background:#fff;
      padding:10px;
      margin:3px;
  }
  h1 {
      font:normal bold 2em/1.8em"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align:left;
      border-bottom:1px solid #999;
      padding:0;
      width:auto
  }
  h2 {
      font:italic bold 1.3em/1.2em"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      padding:0;
      text-align:center;
      margin:20px 0;
  }
  p.pager {
      margin:5px 0 5px;
      font:bold 1em/1em"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color:#999;
  }
  img.question-image {
      display:block;
      max-width:250px;
      margin:10px auto;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
  }
  #choice-block {
      display:block;
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  #submitbutton {
      background:#5a6b8c;
  }
  #submitbutton:hover {
      background:#7b8da6;
  }
  #explanation {
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:20px;
      width:75%;
  }
  .choice-box {
      display:block;
      text-align:center;
      margin:8px auto;
      padding:10px 0;
      border:1px solid #666;
      cursor:pointer;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }
  </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id = "frame"
    role = "content" >
```

And This is the Java
I want to make some modification, please help! Here is the list of modification.

1. when I click on "Check Answer" button then if my answer is wrong
   then both correct and incorrect answer will showing and the
   explanation should comes with a popup with close button or delay
   with 1500ms.
2. Suppose I have 20 question in the quiz and I want to goto question
   No. 10 then I need a navigation menu which help me to go on specific
   question like question no.10.
3. How to show all Question and option Randomly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question - a fiddle URL that isn't even clickable is [not helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn I have updated the question.

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what you've tried and what isn't working. What have you done so far to implement modifications #1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, actually i dont have any knowledge or javascript and i saw this script on this website. so i want to use it. if u can't help me then just let me know how can i show both answer when i click on a wrong option. wrong option in red color is already created and i want to show right answer too when someone click on wrong question. please help.

Comment: can i suffle/random my question by this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230847/javascript-quiz-display-choices-in-a-random-order-using-array-prototype

Comment: anyone can help me??

Comment: is this work for me.. var questions = init.questions;
var question = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)]